# Change BackGround Color from database(WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, background, inotifypropertychanged

and thank you for taking your time to take a look at my questioon,  I looked through several questions and didn't find anything regarding this, so here's what I want to do:

1 - I'd like to have a table like: Colors_Table for example and then save there all the Hex for colors.

2- Set the hex color that is going to be use for my client like Properties_Table and then have a row MainBackGroundColor, and that's the color I'll use for my background.

I don't know if I made myself clear, basically what I want is to be able to set the backbround color from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is clear.  To do this, you can add a background property to your window like this...

```
<Window.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding MyBackgroundColor}"/>
</Window.Background>
```

Note that the color of the brush is binded to property rather than having a hard-coded value.

Then in your code-behind, you can use this...

```
public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        // set color here
        MyBackgroundColor = Colors.Red;
    }
    private Color _myBackgroundColor;
    public Color MyBackgroundColor
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _myBackgroundColor; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _myBackgroundColor)
            {
                _myBackgroundColor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyBackgroundColor");
            }
        }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In this example, the background is red.  If you have a string in hex format, like "#ffaabbcc", you can use this conversion...

```
        MyBackgroundColor =(Color) new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom(null, null, "#ffaabbcc");
```

...and get the result you're looking for.

Notes:

- the '#' should be the first character of the string.

  the first two bytes are the alpha channel